# Android Lint error: Class requires API level 3, current is min is 1

Tags: android, api, sdk

When running my Android app I often get a list of errors, wich says

```
Class requires API level 3 (current min is 1): android.hardware.SensorEventListener
```

I've searched for the correct answer to this, like Android tools > Clear Link Markers, but this doesn't solve the problem. Every once in a while the list of errors keeps coming back. Is it something in my project settings or are my methods deprecated? I've installed the latest SDK for Android 4.4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `manifest` file set the sdk like this based on your requirement..

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: The documentation recommends excluding the `maxSdkVersion` unless you have a really good reason. "There is no need to set the attribute as means of blocking deployment of your application onto new versions of the Android platform as they are released. By design, new versions of the platform are fully backward-compatible"

Answer (score 1):

Restart and invalidate cache if this error just started up for no apparent reason

Answer (score 0):

Change your application minsdk from `Preference>Android>select the api level Android1.6`